# How does a browser render / apply CSS

Tags: css, browser, rendering, render

The title might be a bit misleading, but I couldn't find a better way in describe it in short words.

The question is how does a browser really apply CSS rules if he has given more as one value for the same property.

Let's have an quick example :

```
.foo {
  border-color: green;
  border-bottom-color: black;
  border-bottom-color: blue;
}
```

So does he read the whole class (.foo) and render it THEN or does it take a single property like "border-color: green;" and render it and then render the bottom black and then once again blue ?

Why do I ask this? I wanted to know if classB is more performant as classA  (see in the next example), because you'll use less code to load. But this would only make sense if it won't render over and over the same property.

```
.classA {
  border-top-color: black;
  border-right-color: white;
  border-bottom-color: black;
  border-left-color: black;
}

.classB {
  border-color: black;
  border-right-color: white;
}
```

Comment: You really shouldn't give too much thought about this, unless you're writing websites for TI calculators. But, basically, css is parsed in one go so there are no rerenders.

Comment: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When a browser displays a document, it must combine the document's content with its style information. It processes the document in two stages:

- The browser converts HTML and CSS into the DOM (Document Object Model). The DOM represents the document in the computer's memory. It combines the document's content with its style.
- The browser displays the contents of the DOM.

Comment: User Style Sheets : https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets/User_Style_Sheets